# Jquery Plugin callback in public function

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I've been using this structure (boilerplate rivisited) for my plugin.

```
(function($) {

    $.pluginName = function(element, options) {

        var defaults = {
            foo: 'bar',
            onFoo: function() {}
        }

        var plugin = this;

        plugin.settings = {}

        var $element = $(element),
             element = element;

        plugin.init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            // code goes here
        }

        plugin.foo_public_method = function() {
            // code goes here
        }

        var foo_private_method = function() {
            // code goes here
        }

        plugin.init();

    }

    $.fn.pluginName = function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined == $(this).data('pluginName')) {
                var plugin = new $.pluginName(this, options);
                $(this).data('pluginName', plugin);
            }
        });

    }

})(jQuery);
```

I would like to add a callback to my foo_public_method in this way

```
plugin.foo_public_method = function(data, callback) {
   // code goes here
   if (typeof callback == 'function') {
      callback.call(plugin);
   }
}
```

But I get an error when I try to call this public function with callback

```
$('#element').data('pluginName').foo_public_method(data, callback: function(){//some code});
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: `$('#element').data('pluginName').foo_public_method(data, function(){//some code});`

Comment: try removing `callback:` in `.foo_public_method(data, callback: function(){`

Comment: It is just a typo - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/oesbofmz/1/

Comment: I'm a little stupid, I removed " callback: "and everything went well! Thank you all!